# Аналог редактирования prototype в JS на Python 3

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, prototype

В js, если мне вдруг нужно будет, я смогу добавить новый метод для любого объекта. Например метод `exist` для массива:

```js
Array.prototype.exist = function (value) {
  if (this.indexOf(value) === -1) return false;
  else return true;
};

let arr = [1, 3, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
  console.log(arr.exist(i));
}
```

Можно ли как-то реализовать подобное на питоне?

Comment: Нет, конечно, Python же хороший язык.

Comment: Это очень вредный антипаттерн, запутывающий код и мозги и потенциально ломающий совместимость; даже в javascript так не стоит делать

Comment: Тогда мне нужно делать функцию `exist`, которая будет принимать 2 аргумента, первый - массив, второй - проверяемое значение? `exist(arr, 2)`? Выглядит это непривлекательно( Ну ладно. С тем, что это может путать код, я согласе .

Comment: Для проверки наличия элемента в списке есть очень привлекательное `2 in arr`

Comment: А вообще в питоне так тоже можно (но не нужно), но только для пользовательских классов; для списка добавить метод не получится

Comment: @andreymal это я для примера `exist` написал. Мне нужно сделать метод `find`, который по каждому элементу массива проходит. На JS - `arr.find(value => value.some_property == 'Correct')`, а на Питоне отдельную функцию писать. (Массив у меня объекты содержит)

Comment: @Don2Quixote, для получения индекса элемента в списке есть метод index, отдельную функцию писать не нужно:  https://ideone.com/EFVAnX

Comment: @insolor, Веороятно, вы не поняли, что мне нужно. У меня такой массив:
`[{element: 'a', code: 0}, {element: 'c', code: 1}, {element: 'g', code: 3}, ...]`. Мне нужно выяснить, существует ли в этом массиве такой объект, значение `element` которого совпадает с искомым.

Comment: Так нужно описывать конкретную проблему в вопросе, чтобы мы не гадали. В данном случаем можно list comprehension использовать, опять же без модификации класса list.

Comment: @insolor Так в теме конкретный вопрос: есть ли аналог `prototype` в python? А то, для чего мне это нужно, - это уже вытекающее.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, тогда ответ нет. Если бы вы задали более широкий вопрос, тогда вам ответили как лучше решить вашу проблему.

Comment: @insolor, А за list comprehension спасибо, решает мою проблему, но читабельность этой конструкции оставляет жедать лучшего.